# Online Reservation and Payment System

Tags: payment

we created an online reservation and payment system, we are going to use paypal to pay for the reservation fee.

how do we exactly save the information of our customer and reservation info to our database, after confirming their payment.

how do we confirm that they also paid it?

thanks in advance. as of now we're using the 'pay now' button

Answer (score 0):

You should save the info to the database FIRST, then they can go to the PayPal site.  After that, you can use Instant Payment Notification to mark the order as complete.

https://www.paypal.com/ipn

Answer (score 0):

Paypal provide different methods to make payment; you can redirect user to PayPal from your application without taking customer information (e.g. name, phone, email). PayPal API is rich with multiple set of methods like SetExpressCheckOut, GetExpressCheckOut, DoExpressChckOut.

First please make a contract with PayPal and get the Merchant information; later you can have detailed documented API to talk to them.

Thank you